# How to list all commits and related changes between two different versions using git

Tags: git, diff, commit

I want to list all commits **and changes** for each commit between two different versions .

I have two different versions:

*A:*

```
<project name="gecko.git" path="gecko" remote="mozillaorg" revision="913804d1cc347112fd033df8c18e683db074791f" upstream="v1.4"/>
```

*B:*

```
<project name="gecko.git" path="gecko" remote="mozillaorg" revision="ef52f8028b3f60190f78801ac5dbd879f836a498" upstream="v1.4"/>
```

Now I can use

```
git diff 913804d1cc347112fd033df8c18e683db074791f ef52f8028b3f60190f78801ac5dbd879f836a498
```

two show all changes between *A* and *B* like:

```
diff --git a/b2g/config/emulator-ics/sources.xml b/b2g/config/emulator-ics/sources.xml
index 2f574d3..3274ceb 100644
--- a/b2g/config/emulator-ics/sources.xml
+++ b/b2g/config/emulator-ics/sources.xml
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
     <copyfile dest="Makefile" src="core/root.mk"/>
   </project>
   <project name="fake-dalvik" path="dalvik" remote="b2g" revision="ca1f327d5acc198bb4be62fa51db2c039032c9ce"/>
-  <project name="gaia.git" path="gaia" remote="mozillaorg" revision="c0b571522702f4d9fb6aba10300e9cbc55c2d084"/>
+  <project name="gaia.git" path="gaia" remote="mozillaorg" revision="ce6c3d8fbd123dc65e8d2dd1f90403e24fa36dfe"/>
   <project name="gonk-misc" path="gonk-misc" remote="b2g" revision="81e894545b87ea2cf9e78f56a2cd1d2a5adc7a25"/>
   <project name="rilproxy" path="rilproxy" remote="b2g" revision="827214fcf38d6569aeb5c6d6f31cb296d1f09272"/>
   <project name="platform_hardware_ril" path="hardware/ril" remote="b2g" revision="d11f524d00cacf5ba0dfbf25e4aa2158b1c3a036"/>
diff --git a/b2g/config/emulator-jb/sources.xml b/b2g/config/emulator-jb/sources.xml
index d4038f1..a6520b6 100644
--- a/b2g/config/emulator-jb/sources.xml
+++ b/b2g/config/emulator-jb/sources.xml
@@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
   </project>
   <project name="rilproxy" path="rilproxy" remote="b2g" revision="827214fcf38d6569aeb5c6d6f31cb296d1f09272"/>
   <project name="fake-libdvm" path="dalvik" remote="b2g" revision="d50ae982b19f42f0b66d08b9eb306be81687869f"/>
-  <project name="gaia" path="gaia" remote="mozillaorg" revision="c0b571522702f4d9fb6aba10300e9cbc55c2d084"/>
+  <project name="gaia" path="gaia" remote="mozillaorg" revision="ce6c3d8fbd123dc65e8d2dd1f90403e24fa36dfe"/>
   <project name="gonk-misc" path="gonk-misc" remote="b2g" revision="81e894545b87ea2cf9e78f56a2cd1d2a5adc7a25"/>
   <project name="moztt" path="external/moztt" remote="b2g" revision="7beaabe1187b688ef560607912577c614a038533"/>
   <project name="apitrace" path="external/apitrace" remote="apitrace" revision="8a4baf82a131a7853cf7e7f9cf74253927b2f355"/>
diff --git a/b2g/config/emulator-kk/sources.xml b/b2g/config/emulator-kk/sources.xml
index 59429f5..a727976 100644
--- a/b2g/config/emulator-kk/sources.xml
+++ b/b2g/config/emulator-kk/sources.xml
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@
   <project name="platform_build" path="build" remote="b2g" revision="65fba428f8d76336b33ddd9e15900357953600ba">
     <copyfile dest="Makefile" src="core/root.mk"/>
   </project>
-  <project name="gaia" path="gaia" remote="mozillaorg" revision="c0b571522702f4d9fb6aba10300e9cbc55c2d084"/>
+  <project name="gaia" path="gaia" remote="mozillaorg" revision="ce6c3d8fbd123dc65e8d2dd1f90403e24fa36dfe"/>
   <project name="fake-libdvm" path="dalvik" remote="b2g" revision="d50ae982b19f42f0b66d08b9eb306be81687869f"/>
   <project name="gonk-misc" path="gonk-misc" remote="b2g" revision="81e894545b87ea2cf9e78f56a2cd1d2a5adc7a25"/>
```

With output as above I can't tell which change is related to which commit, so it's kind of hard for me to narrow down some specific bugs.

My question is how to list all commits **and changes** for each commit between two versions, like

```
commit f3001d8f7099d582916b96340a8e2f0d19930c01
<Changes in this commit>

commit 185711685900f71dea5cdd17ae4a0c02847c68d2
<Changes in this commit>

commit af7ca17248731d6b98772b0ab051d918fb7f9b84
<Changes in this commit>
```

Comment: Haven't read over your whole question yet, but it's likely that you'll find your answer if you read this: [Pro Git: 6.1 Git Tools - Revision Selection - Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
git log -p 913804..ef52f8
```

`git` will properly understand hashes given enough characters to make them unambigouous.

Answer (score 2):

You may pass a commit range to `git show`:

```
git show first_commit..last_commit
```

There is a nice explanation about how to use commit ranges in this link if you want to do something more complex: http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#Commit-Ranges